# Procedure entry point __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located libstdc++-6.dll

Tags: python, c++, c, ctypes

Appreciate this question has been asked and answered for several cases but I'm still having issues. My directory structure is laid out as such:

```
models/
    bs/
        __init__.py
        values.py
    optlib/
        Makefile
        bin/
            optlib.so       # generated after compilation/linking
            libstdc++-6.dll
        inc/
            optlib.h
            stats.h
        obj/
            optlib.o        # generated after compilation/linking
            stats.o         # generated after compilation/linking
        src/
            optlib.cc
            stats.cc
```

In short, my source files are in `src`, header files in `inc`, object files output to `obj` and the shared library file output to `bin`.

I've compiled and linked C/C++ libraries using the following commands (extracted from `Makefile`):

```
g++ -c -Iinc -o obj/optlib.o src/optlib.cc
g++ -c -Iinc -o obj/stats.o src/stats.cc

g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,bin/optlib.so -o bin/optlib.so obj/optlib.o obj/stats.o
```

I'm using MinGW on a Windows 7 machine and attempting to access the shared library from Python using `ctypes`. I've placed the `libstdc++-6.dll` file from `C:\MinGW\bin` into the `bin` directory which contains the shared library, `optlib.so` as many of the posts suggest.

My Python code is as follows (note the `__init__.py` imports `values.py`):

```
# neither the os.path.abspath method of building the path works...
fn = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'optlib', 'bin', 'optlib.so'))
print type(fn) # returns <type 'unicode'>
# or actually implicitly typing it out
#fn= u'C:\\Users\\striji\\Desktop\\models\\optlib\\bin\\optlib.so'
LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH=0x00000008
kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32')
kernel32.LoadLibraryExW.restype = c_void_p
hMod = kernel32.LoadLibraryExW(fn, None, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH)
lib = CDLL(fn, handle=hMod)

def fcn(x):
    lib.c_func.argtypes = [c_double]
    lib.c_func.restype = c_double
    x = byref(c_double(x))
    return lib.c_func(x)
```

When I attempt to import the module using the following:

```
>>> from models import bs
```

I get the following error:

[image: WTF]

`C:\MinGW\bin` is on my `PATH` variable. Source code is actually `C++` wrapped in `extern "C"` so that `ctypes` can see it. These are very simple `C++` functions. If you need to see the source, I can post.

Question then is twofold. First, how do I fix the immediate problem. Second, is it possible to simplify the compilation and linking process so it is system agnostic (i.e. compiles and links on Mac OSX and Linux)?

Comment: The least intrusive and most thread-safe option is to call `kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32');` `kernel32.LoadLibraryExW.restype = c_void_p;` `hMod = kernel32.LoadLibraryExW(absolute_path_to_optlib, None, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH)`. Then wrap the loaded module reference, e.g. `lib = CDLL('optlib.so', handle=hMod)`.

Comment: FYI, it should be `lib.c_func.argtypes = [c_double]`. The attribute is `argtypes` with an "s" at the end. But then your call is wrong because you specify the type as `double` but pass a `double *` via `byref`.

Comment: Thanks for this, will give it a shot and report.

Comment: This did not solve it, I still get the popup error. The parameters for the C function are defined as `const double& x`.

Comment: This solves it while in the same directory as the shared library. However, when attempting to import the module, I receive the same error.

Comment: It does work if use a unicode string that's an *absolute path*, e.g.  `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'optlib', 'bin', 'optlib.so'))`. If you're using Python 3 that's already a unicode string. If you're using Python 2 you can use `u''` literals, or the `decode` method, or `unicode` , etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working. Updated OP with revised code.

Comment: Possibly some other module or library is loading an older version of libstdc++-6. Please try a minimal package -- just a mocked up `models` package that only loads your DLL and nothing else. If the problem persists verify that your version of libstdc++-6.dll actually exports the function `__gxx_personality_v0`. Just `CDLL` load libstdc++-6.dll using an absolute path, and try to access the name as an attribute.